# Facing a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'gurobipy.LinExpr' and 'GenExprAbs' when using .abs_() in gurobipy

Tags: python-3.x, gurobi

I am solving a re-districting integer linear program using Gurobipy and I want to minimise the sum of two expressions in my objective function, each involving the absolute value function.

The variables and constants I need for the objective function is as follows:

```
# Partisan lean (WLOG, lean to a party) of each precinct; binary variable l_i == 1 if the precinct leans towards a party, 0 otherwise
l  = {(i):opt_model.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.BINARY,
                        name="l_{0}".format(i)) 
for i in set_I}

# Decision variable for n precincts assigned to m districts; binary variable x_i_j == 1 means ith precinct assigned to jth district 
x  = {(i,j):opt_model.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.BINARY,
                        name="x_{0}_{1}".format(i,j)) 
for i in set_I for j in set_J}

# Population for each of n precincts; integer variable pp_i
pp  ={(i):opt_model.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.INTEGER,
                        lb=0, 
                        name="pp_{0}".format(i)) 
for i in set_I}

# Target population
V = 9900
targ = math.floor(V // m)

# actual proportion of lean
actual_proportion = gp.quicksum(l[i] for i in set_I)/n
```

Here is my objective function.

```
# Define the objective function
obj = gp.quicksum(
    gp.quicksum(gp.abs_(pp[i] * x[i, j] - targ) for i in set_I) for j in set_J
) + gp.quicksum(
    gp.quicksum(
        gp.abs_(
            l[i] * x[i, j] / gp.quicksum(x[i, j] for i in set_I) - actual_proportion
        )
        for i in set_I
    )
    for j in set_J
)

model.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

However, I ran into the error that is `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'gurobipy.LinExpr' and 'GenExprAbs'`. I have already additionally tried stating the two separate expressions to be summed in the objective function in separate lines first and having a third line that states that the variable `obj` = the two expressions added together. However, I am still facing the same error. How could I still include the absolute value function without getting the error?

Comment: put this question on or.stackexchange.com. It will be easier to formulate there. Also I think dividing by a variable is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Model.addVars()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/py_model_addvars.html) to add variables - this is more straightforward than defining your own dictionaries.

The absolute function requires adding another auxiliary variable to capture the result, as shown [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/py_model_agc_abs.html).